# How to customize templates in vim-latex

Tags: templates, vim, latex, customization, fedora

I'm trying to use vim-latex, and as the existing templates are annoyingly simple and unsatisfactory, I'm trying to build some of my own. However, after composing my own templates and stored in "/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates", nothing happens. The software simply won't scan for new templates. Did I miss some steps to make it work?

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have flagged this for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what's happening. If there's any one who ran into a similar problem, please check whether you have installed that plugin in your OS repo. I'm using fedora, and accidentally installed vim-latex from the repo, thus the place those templates are really located is

"/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates".

So either remove the add-on installed from the OS repo and reinstall it in "~/.vim/", or copy the templates to that folder is the solution to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you know it's ok (it's even encouraged) to accept your own answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. But it said that I should wait for additional 14 hours to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem using Xubuntu.  There the template files are stored at `/usr/share/vim/addons/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates/`.  But simply adding a new template file there won't create a new menu entry in gvim: you must also make a soft link from your new template file in the directory above to `/var/lib/vim/addons/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates/your_new_template.tex`